# PHPMailer fails when try to send 2 mails

Tags: php, file, email, phpmailer

I'm trying to send 2 different mails at once. 1 email is only text, the other mail with is with an attachment.

I tried on 2 different ways to handle this.
My first attempt was to have 2 files. One to send a mail to the customer. The other page to send a mail to us. My second attempt was to try to combine to one page.

I will first explain my first attempt when trying with 2 different pages.

I included them likes this after the validation of the form is succesfull and inserted to my database:

```
include_once './mailklant.php';
include_once './mailsp.php';
```

`mailklant.php` code is (SMTP connection deleted, but works perfect.):

```
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'To customer: Your order ' . toxInput::get('po');
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML('Hello '. $toxUser->data()->fullname . ',<br>Your order '. toxInput::get('po'));
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

and `mailsp.php` looks like this:

```
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'To us: Klant: #KLANTNAAM# heeft een nieuwe order geplaatst <> ' . toxInput::get('po');
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML('Beste,<br>' . $toxUser->data()->fullname . ' heeft een nieuwe order geplaatst voor #KLANTNAAM#.');
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//die($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . 'spoos/data/testdata/'. toxInput::get('po').'.xlsx');
$mail->addAttachment($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/spoos/data/testdata/'. toxInput::get('po').'.xlsx');

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

The problem is. `mailklant.php` runs succesfully but `mailsp.php` does nothing. even not a error back. I receive only 1 mail.
When I add `die('test');` at line 2 in `mailsp.php`. When I run the script it return `test` so the page is included. BTW the excel file is also valid and right path to the file. It will proofs in my second attempt.

My second attempt was to combine this 2 files into one:

```
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'To customer: Your order ' . toxInput::get('po');
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML('Hello '. $toxUser->data()->fullname . ',<br>Your order '. toxInput::get('po'));
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

if (!$mail->send()) {
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

$mail->Subject = 'To us: Klant: #KLANTNAAM# heeft een nieuwe order geplaatst <> ' . toxInput::get('po');
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML('Beste,<br>' . $toxUser->data()->fullname . ' heeft een nieuwe order geplaatst voor #KLANTNAAM#.');
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//die($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . 'spoos/data/testdata/'. toxInput::get('po').'.xlsx');
$mail->addAttachment($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/spoos/data/testdata/'. toxInput::get('po').'.xlsx');

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Then i receive 3 emails. One to customer, without the excel file. 2 times to us, included the excel file.

When im trying to use this:

```
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearReplyTos();
$mail->ClearCustomHeaders();
$mail->setFrom('', '');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('', '');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('', '');
```

I still receiving 3 mails. 1 to customer, 2 times to us.

Comment: This is very confused. Cut down your code to the critical parts. From what I can see, your code is doing exactly what you're asking it to. It's hard to see what you're asking for.

Comment: Yeah thats the problem. It seems allright, but i explain it isnt. These are the critical parts. If i didn't post the SMTP setup, people would ask and say i dont provide enough information lol. You say `your code is doing exactly what you're asking it to` so you know what i want but then you say it hard to see what you are asking?

Comment: Updated, deleted important php codes.

Comment: Your original two file approach would fail on the second one because you were unconditionally requiring the autoloader twice. Your second approach looks better, but it's not clear where you're putting that additional snippet (it should be between the two sends) and you're doing something strange calling those functions with empty params - that will achieve nothing.

Comment: I removed the data for publishing on stackoverflow.
The email functions works fine, the data is right. It sends the emails. But 3 three times. With my second approach it sends 1 times the mail for customer, and 2 times the mail to 'us' with the excel file.

Comment: So set a breakpoint, catch it sending twice, then you'll know why.